# How to run unit tests with .NET version 4.6.2 in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vstest, target-framework, runsettings

I'm trying to resolve this warning from unit test runs in Visual Studio:

> [6/7/2019 7:16:21 PM Warning] Test run will use DLL(s) built for
>   framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 and platform X64. Following
>   DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings. MyProject.Tests.dll
>   is built for Framework 4.6.2 and Platform AnyCPU. Go to
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more
>   details on managing these settings.

I know that I need to update the runsettings file with a targetframework version matching the framework of the unit test project (4.6.2). I just can't figure out what the magic string is.

Here's the starting point:

```xml
<!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>

    <!-- [x86] | x64  
      - You can also change it from menu Test, Test Settings, Default Processor Architecture -->
    <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>

    <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 -->
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameworkVersion> 
    <!--
    TargetFrameworkVersion needs to be updated, but documentation is unclear on how
    cf. https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/issues/163
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    -->     
  </RunConfiguration>
```

Every value I can find to try results in the following exception:

> [6/7/2019 8:34:20 PM Error] Failed to configure settings for runsettings plugin 'VSTest Run Configuration' as it threw following exception:
>   'An error occurred while loading the settings.  Error: Invalid setting 'RunConfiguration'. Invalid value 'net462' specified for 'TargetFrameworkVersion'..'
>   Please contact the plugin author.
>
> [6/7/2019 8:34:20 PM Diagnostic] Generate test run settings exception:System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while loading the settings.  Error: Invalid setting 'RunConfiguration'. Invalid value 'net462' specified for 'TargetFrameworkVersion'..
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VSTest.TestRunSettingsService.ValidateRunConfigurationSettings(XPathNavigator runSettingsNavigator)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VSTest.TestRunSettingsService.MergeRunSettingsAndFindCompatibleSources(Architecture& platform, FrameworkVersion& framework, String resultsDirectory, String solutionDirectory, IDictionary`2 sourceSettings, IXPathNavigable inputRunSettings, String& incompatibleSourcesWarning)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VSTest.TestRunSettingsService.AddRunSettings(IXPathNavigable inputRunSettingDocument, IRunSettingsConfigurationInfo configurationInfo, ILogger log)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.GenerateTestRunSettings(RunSettingConfigurationInfoState infoState)

Values I've tried:

- .NETFramework,Version=v4.6
- .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2
- v4.6.2
- net46
- net462
- Framework46

Similar:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/236358/vstestconsoleexe-in-testwindow-on-1570-preview-3-d.html
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/issues/163
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/579073/test-discovery-reporting-dlls-do-not-match.html

Comment: Did you found out how to run tests with v4.6.2? The answer below didn't help in my case

Comment: It didn't work for me either. Still looking. A friend at Microsoft told me to just upgrade to .NET Core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had same issue with Framework 4.6.1 tests. Since the original post, the page referenced by the https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/579073/test-discovery-reporting-dlls-do-not-match.html link was updated with a note that the issue is fixed in Visual Studio 16.2, which was released July 24. I upgraded, removed the entire RunConfiguration section from the .runsettings file, and now the unit tests run without error.

Comment: I still see the warning on 16.2.1. Confirmed that it is resolved in Visual Studio Preview (16.3.0 Preview 1.0) though so it must be coming downing the pipe at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I simply removed "TargetFrameworkVersion" and it worked in my case.  I guess Visual Studio auto selects the correct framework if this field is not specified.

```
<!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>

    <!-- [x86] | x64  
      - You can also change it from menu Test, Test Settings, Default Processor Architecture -->
    <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>

  </RunConfiguration>
```